# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

i have python 3.2.3 on windows.
installed matplotlib

i'm trying to do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
File "E:\programs\python 3.2.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 24, in <module>
import matplotlib.colorbar
File "E:\programs\python 3.2.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 29, in <module>
import matplotlib.collections as collections
File "E:\programs\python 3.2.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 23, in <module>
import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
File "E:\programs\python 3.2.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 50, in <module>
import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
File "E:\programs\python 3.2.3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 5, in <module>
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
ImportError: No module named urllib.request
```

any idea?

Comment: try installing urllib

Comment: How did you install mpl?

Comment: used "matplotlib-1.3.1.win32-py3.2.exe" from the site. had problems with missing dateutil and pyparsing - installed them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Sorry I am not a windows user and can't provide much sensible in the way of how to fix this.  Have you seen this page http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install urllib.
This is required by matplotlib

Comment: the problem is... it seams i DO HAVE urllib... i have a urllib dir in my lib dir, i have all kind of *urllib.py... - so i'm not sure of what does it mean to 'install' it... how can i know?

Answer (score -1):

Look Install `urllib` from : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/urllib2_file/0.2.1

Or if you was instaled `pip` you can use `sudo pip install urllib`

Comment: thanks. but... Does not work with Python 3.0+ as urllib2 has been merged with urllib

Comment: The question is about a windows box, `sudo` won't help here.